# Downgrade Word 2013 Add-in project to be Word 2010 Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I created an Office Word 2013 project and the project was stable.

[image: screenshot]

But now I need to downgrade it to an Office Word 2010 Add-in project

**More details** I mean that I want the same project which was working with Word 2013 to work with Word 2010 without creating a new project.

How can I do that?

Comment: Remove all of the features and code and references that are not compatible with Word 2010 and replace them with their Word 2010 equivalents.

Comment: This is a VSTO add-in, it appears?

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your reply I will try to do that and I will return with the result

Comment: @CindyMeister no it is word add-in.

Comment: That picture looks like a VSTO add-in, to me. Are you writing the code in C# or in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you seen this page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/running-solutions-in-different-versions-of-microsoft-office?view=vs-2017? Note that you'd need to embed interop types (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/development-best-practices-for-com-vsto-and-vba-add-ins-in-office?view=vs-2017) for the solution to be compatibile with an older version. If it relies on a link to the PIAs then it won't go "backwards". In general, it's always better to program using the *oldest* version of Word you plan to support. The other way around is frought with problems...